Telegram bot - setMyCommands and getMyCommands implementation
Further to this question, I'm trying to figure out how to actually implement getMyCommands. There isn't much documentation online.
I'm still a novice and have assumed that the following should be close to the correct method, but it fails.
Within the bot class, I first attempt to assign commands:
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

...
List<BotCommand> commands = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setMyCommands(){
        commands.add(new BotCommand("start", "Starts the bot"));
        commands.add(new BotCommand("menu", "Opens the menu"));
        commands.add(new BotCommand("next", "Next menu page"));
        commands.add(new BotCommand("back", "Previous menu page"));
        commands.add(new BotCommand("help", "Explains how to use bot"));
        }

In the Main method, I have called the following, so that the commands are set on startup:
bot.setMyCommands();

To both check that the above assignment works as intended, and to feed into the /help command, which will list the bots commands, within the bot class I have tried the following:
public List<BotCommand> actualcmds = getMyCommands();
    public List<BotCommand> getMyCommands() {
        return actualcmds;
}

...
@Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

I have checked and actualcmds is null at this point.
StringBuilder hlp = new StringBuilder();
                hlp.append(helptxt);
                for (BotCommand blah : actualcmds) {
                    hlp.append("\n");
                    hlp.append(blah);

                    }
//never reaches this point
                System.out.println(hlp);

As per above, it doesn't seem that the commands have either been assigned, or whether I have used getMyCommands correctly.
Any advice?

So "actualcmds" variable is a result of "getMyCommands()" method, which returns "actualcmds"? This doesn't make any sense. As of your code snippets, you haven't populated "actualcmds" anywhere.

That is the issue. I don't understand how to use getMyCommands to assign the output to a variable. What would be the correct way?

Although it's not very clear to me what your code is trying to achieve. But here is a snippet along those lines.
public class CommandsDemoBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    private String commandsHelpText;

    public void start() throws TelegramApiException {
        new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class).registerBot(this);

        List<BotCommand> commands = Arrays.asList(
                new BotCommand("start", "Starts the bot"),
                new BotCommand("menu", "Opens the menu"),
                new BotCommand("next", "Next menu page"),
                new BotCommand("back", "Previous menu page"),
                new BotCommand("help", "Explains how to use bot")
        );

        super.execute(new SetMyCommands(commands, null, null));

        // saving result text to a class field, but you could also save commands list if needed
        this.commandsHelpText = "Usage:\n" + commands.stream()
                .map(command -> '/' + command.getCommand() + " - " + command.getDescription())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

        System.out.println(this.commandsHelpText);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        try {
            if (update.hasMessage()) {
                Message message = update.getMessage();
                String messageText = message.getText();
                switch (messageText) {
                    case "/help":
                        super.execute(SendMessage.builder()
                                .chatId(message.getChatId())
                                .text(commandsHelpText)
                                .build());
                        break;
                    case "/start":
                        // ...
                }
            }
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("onUpdateReceived failed", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return ..
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return ..
    }
}

public class Application() {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TelegramApiException {
        new CommandsDemoBot().start();
    }
}

Result: bot is started, it has specified commands in standard Menu.
Commands are listed in "commandsText" variable.
"/help" bot command replies with:

Usage:
/start - Starts the bot
/menu - Opens the menu
/next - Next menu page
/back - Previous menu page
/help - Explains how to use bot

This text is also printed to console on start.
telegrambots library version 6.x

Thank you. This achieves the intended result of returning the commands and have marked it as an answer. However, it looks like it uses the variable to which we assigned the commands previously - if in the future the commands are modified via Bot Father, I'm not sure this would still return the correct list of commands? That was partly the reason for my question about getMyCommands which I assume can handle this situation. I'm a novice at this, so maybe the above is not a realistic problem.
